# How to detect Double-clicking in window titlebar (Chrome) in javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, minimize, maximize

In my web app I have event listeners for scrolling and resizing events. But how do I detect resizing through double clicking? It destroys my layout and I want to prevent that.

Comment: So you are saying it does not fire onresize event?

Comment: Hi! window.addEventListener("scroll", my_function); and
    window.addEventListener("resize", my_funtion); do not fire in this case